# Create folders in attachments in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I would like to create folders in attachments in PDF with PDFBox. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. I have tried to create a COSDictionary with Folder type. The result looks similar in the pdf source as in my working examples which I have created with other tools namely

```
<<
/Type (Folder) /Name /ParentFolder
```

but it doesn't appear in the PDF when I open it with Acrobat Reader. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the `/Type` is `(Folder)`? The value of a `/Type` field is normally a name object and not a string. Furthermore, the PDF specification doesn't have any information about a `/Folder` type.

Comment: Not 100% sure @gettalong. I checked a PDF file which was created with iText. I'm trying the achieve the same with PDFBox. `2 0 obj <</Type/Folder/CreationDate(D:20201207232942+01'00')/ModDate(D:20201207232942+01'00')/ID 1/Name(Folder 1)/Parent 1 0 R/FileAttachment 6 0 R>>
endobj`

Comment: Okay, so the type is actually `/Folder` which is a good sign. Can you post a bit more details on the structure involved, e.g. what is object (1,0)? Where in the catalog is this folder structure linked?